# Get element's value

Tags: javascript, html, element

I'm trying to check an element's value but it returns `undefined` though it works when I'm checking its class.

HTML:

```
<div class='cube' value='test' onclick='checkCube(this)'></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function checkCube(cube) {      // - there's either one of those lines, not both)
    var check = cube.value;         //This is not working,
    var check = cube.className;     //This is.
    console.log(check);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`value` property is only supported for *input elements*

Use `getAttribute` for *non-input* elements

```
var check = cube.getAttribute("value");
```

Answer (score 2):

It will be better to use **[`data-* attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*)** when you attach extra properties (not the tag global attributes) to your elements :

```
<div class='cube' data-value='test' onclick='checkCube(this)'></div>
```

Then use **[`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)** to retrieve the attribute value like :

```
var check = cube.dataset.value;
```

Comment: Yup. didn't know that one before!

Answer (score 0):

you can get by using [getAttributes](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp).The getAttribute() method returns the value of the attribute with the specified name, of an element.

```js
function checkCube(cube) {     
    var check = cube.value;         
    var check = cube.className;     
    console.log(cube.getAttribute("value"));
}
```

```html
<div class='cube' value='test' onclick='checkCube(this)'>click Over Me</div>
```

Comment: I want it to be an empty element hence it won't have any text in it.
Already got a solution by gurviner372, 
Thanks anyway though :D

Answer (score 0):

Do as following.

```js
function checkCube(cube) {    
     var check = cube.getAttribute("value"); 
     alert(check);
   }
```

```html
<div class='cube' value='test' onclick="checkCube(this)">Click me to get Value</div>
```